# How to have big local drive available both from Window and Linux in dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to have very big (terabytes) drive, available both under Windows and Linux, readable, writable. I don't need permissions support on this drive.

How to do that? Which filesystem format satisfies these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linux can read and write to NTFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions), native to Windows. Sharing a large external NTFS drive has posed no problem for me using it for photos, documents and other data. You can also access the drive containing Windows, though avoid writing to the System drive Windows folder or modifying anything on root C:.

You *could* use other formats, such as exFAT, that would require [adding a package to Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working), or ext[*n*], which requires a third-party tool such as [DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) for read-only access, but NTFS should work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as installed.